# Crontab + ubuntu + java not working

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, cron

If I directly run the bellow code in terminal it is working perfect.

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /var/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/email_linux/notification_18.jar
```

But when I set the same as a crontab in ubuntu server then it is not working.

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar /var/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/email_linux/notification_18.jar
```

Any one know why unexpected behavior?

Comment: Please define: 'not working'

Comment: @jzd In the sense the jar is not executing.

Answer (score 1):

The crontab task is executed under a different user from the one with which you are testing the call. JBoss depends on a number of environment variables, which are probably undefined in that context. So find out what that particular JAR needs from the environment and then add it into a shell script which you run from the cron task (instead of directly running `java` from cron).

Comment: I have created following into sh file 

/usr/bin/java -jar /var/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/email_linux/notification_18.jar
now added following code in crontab

*/3 * * * * sh /var/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/email_linux/startup.sh
But some how it is not working. How to know that list of environment variable to setup path

Comment: Start with the variables which are defined in your shell, where everything works, and look for anything JBoss-specific and/or Java-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the absolute paths in the source code if you are reading or writing to a file, even if the jar file and the reading file are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved after specifying absolute path