# schedule a pi4j / Java task using crontab

Tags: java, linux, cron, pi4j

I want to run a Java / pi4j Task ([Script ControlGpioExample](http://pi4j.com/example/control.html)) periodically using crontab on my Raspberry PI.

This code works well on the Terminal:

```
sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample
```

In Crontab I added the following line (in this case at 19:58):

```
00 20 * * * sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' 
ControlGpioExample >/dev/null/ 2>&1
```

However, this job did not start at 20:00 nor did I get any further information using ...

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Other stackoverflow users had similar problems with [Cronetab not running Java Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668434/crontab-not-running-java), so I also tried this:

```
00 20 * * * sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*'     
ControlGpioExample > /var/log/javacron.log 2> /var/log/javacron-err.log 
>/dev/null/ 2>&1
```

Again, Crontab shows only that the code had been executed but no error message!

Problems of other users suggest that perhaps something with my [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979661/crontab-doesnt-work-for-run-java-class) or [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449546/crontab-ubuntu-java-not-working) seems to be incorrect? How I can I find this out, what else do I have to set to run this script? Please help, I already try to fix this problem for 2 days!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Crontab+java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL; DR

```
> /dev/null/
```

seems wrong to me, because of the extra `/` at the end.

What about this?

```
00 20 * * * sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample >/var/log/javacron.log 2>/var/log/javacron-err.log
```

Or that:

```
00 20 * * * sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ControlGpioExample >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Oh, that was the problem! Thank you, you saved me many hours in further research!